# Cant put background in the widnow

Tags: java

Im trying to put a background in the window with a bufferedimage but dont load, idk why but im sure its not the path i check many times.

This is the code of the window:

```
package main;
import java.awt.Canvas;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import gameObjects.Constants;
import graphics.Asserts;
import input.Keyboard;
import input.Mouse;
import states.LoadingState;
import states.State;

public class Window extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private Canvas canvas;
    public static Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    private BufferStrategy bs;
    private Graphics g;
    private final int FPS = 60;
    private double TARGETTIME = 1000000000/FPS;
    private double delta = 0;
    private int AVERAGEFPS = FPS;
    
    private Keyboard keyboard;
    private Mouse mouse;
    
    public Window() {
        setTitle("GTA6");
        setSize(Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        canvas = new Canvas();
        keyboard = new Keyboard();
        mouse = new Mouse();
        
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT));
        canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT));
        canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT));
        canvas.setFocusable(true);
        
        add(canvas);
        canvas.addKeyListener(keyboard);
        canvas.addMouseListener(mouse);
        canvas.addMouseMotionListener(mouse);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Window().start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long now = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        int frames = 0;
        long time = 0;
        
        init();
        
        while(running) {
            now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / TARGETTIME;
            time += (now - lastTime);
            lastTime = now;
                
            if(delta >= 1) {
                update();
                draw();
                delta --;
                frames++;
            }
            if(time >= 1000000000) {
                AVERAGEFPS = frames;
                frames = 0;
                time = 0;
            }
        }
        
        stop();
    }
    
    private void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }
    
    private void stop() {
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private void update() {
        keyboard.update();
        mouse.update();
        State.getState().update();
    }
    
    private void draw() {
        bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs==null) {
            canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        
        g.drawImage(Asserts.background, 0, 0, Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT, null);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT);
        
        State.getState().draw(g);
        
        g.drawString(""+AVERAGEFPS, 10, 10);
        
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
    
    private void init() {
        Thread loadingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Asserts.init();
            }});
        
        State.changeState(new LoadingState(loadingThread));
    }

}
```

This is the code where i have the paths:

```
package graphics;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class Asserts {
    
    public static boolean loaded = false;
    public static float count = 0;
    public static float MAX_COUNT = 460;
    
    public static BufferedImage background;
    
    //player
    
    public static BufferedImage[] skinPlayer = new BufferedImage[4];
    
    public static BufferedImage player, icon, greyButton, blueButton;
    
    public static BufferedImage[] life = new BufferedImage[11];
    
    //effects
    
    public static BufferedImage speed;
    
    public static BufferedImage playerProtect;
    
    //power ups
    
    public static BufferedImage extraLife, portect, doubleFire, score;
    
    //laser
    
    public static BufferedImage laserRed, laserGreen, laserBlue;
    
    //meteors
    
    public static BufferedImage[] bigsMeteors = new BufferedImage[4];
    
    public static BufferedImage[] medsMeteors = new BufferedImage[2];
    
    public static BufferedImage[] smallsMeteors = new BufferedImage[2];
    
    public static BufferedImage[] tiniesMeteors = new BufferedImage[2];
    
    //explosions
    
    public static BufferedImage[] explosions = new BufferedImage[8];
    
    //enemy
    
    public static BufferedImage enemy;
    
    //fonts
    
    public static Font fontBig, fontMed;
    
    //sounds
    
    public static Clip backgroundMusic, explosion, playerLose, playerShoot, ufoShoot;
    
    public static void init() {
        for(int i=0; i < skinPlayer.length; i++) {
            skinPlayer[i] = loadImage("src/skins/playerShip" + (i+1) + ".png");
        }
        
        background = loadImage("src/resources/background.png");
        
        player = loadImage("src/skins/playerShip1.png");
        
        speed = loadImage("res/turbo_effects/fire08.png");
        
        extraLife = loadImage("src/powerUps/pill_red.png");
        
        portect = loadImage("src/powerUps/shield_silver.png");
        
        doubleFire = loadImage("src/powerUps/things_silver.png");
        
        score = loadImage("src/powerUps/star_silver.png");
        
        laserRed = loadImage("res/laser/laserRed01.png");
        
        laserGreen = loadImage("res/laser/laserGreen11.png");
        
        laserBlue = loadImage("res/laser/laserBlue01.png");
        
        playerProtect = loadImage("src/powerUps/shield1.png");
        
        for(int i=0; i < bigsMeteors.length; i++) {
            bigsMeteors[i] = loadImage("res/meteors/meteorGrey_big" + (i + 1) + ".png");
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i < medsMeteors.length; i++) {
            medsMeteors[i] = loadImage("res/meteors/meteorGrey_med" + (i + 1) + ".png");
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i < smallsMeteors.length; i++) {
            smallsMeteors[i] = loadImage("res/meteors/meteorGrey_small" + (i + 1) + ".png");
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i < tiniesMeteors.length; i++) {
            tiniesMeteors[i] = loadImage("res/meteors/meteorGrey_tiny" + (i + 1) + ".png");
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i < explosions.length; i++) {
            explosions[i] = loadImage("res/explosions/" + i + ".png");
        }
        
        enemy = loadImage("res/enemis/ufoRed.png");
        
        for(int i=0; i < life.length; i++) {
            life[i] = loadImage("res/numbers/numeral" + i + ".png");
        }
        
        icon = loadImage("res/numbers/playerLife1_blue.png");
        
        //font
        
        fontBig = loadFont("/resources/font.ttf", 42);
        
        fontMed = loadFont("/resources/font.ttf" , 20);
        
        //sound
        
        backgroundMusic = loadSound("src/sounds/backgroundMusic.wav");
        
        explosion = loadSound("src/sounds/explosion.wav");
        
        playerLose = loadSound("src/sounds/playerLoose.wav");
        
        playerShoot = loadSound("src/sounds/playerShoot.wav");
        
        ufoShoot = loadSound("src/sounds/ufoShoot.wav");
        
        //menu
        
        greyButton = loadImage("res/ui/grey_button03.png");
        
        blueButton = loadImage("res/ui/blue_button00.png");
        
        loaded = true;

    }
    
    public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
        count++;
        return Loader.ImageLoader(path);
    }
    
    public static Font loadFont(String path, int size) {
        count++;
        return Loader.loadFont(path, size);
    }
    
    public static Clip loadSound(String path) {
        count++;
        return Loader.loadSound(path);
    }
    
}
```

and this is the code where i load the image

```
package graphics;

import java.awt.Font;

import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class Loader {

    private static Clip clip;
    
    public static BufferedImage ImageLoader(String path) {
        try {
            File archivo = new File(path);
            return ImageIO.read(archivo);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public static Font loadFont(String path, int size) {
        Font font, ttfBase;
        InputStream myStream = null;
        try {
            myStream = Loader.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
            ttfBase = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, myStream);
            font = ttfBase.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, size);
            return font;
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public static Clip loadSound(String path) {
        try {
            File file = new File(path);
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(ais);
            return clip;
        } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

i check the path and im sure its oky maybe the code is not in the right place or something

Comment: Don't do `src/skins/`, `src` will not exist once your program is compiled and exported.  Instead, make use of the fact that these resources will become embedded (assuming your build process includes them in the resulting Jar).  Then, instead of using `File` to try and load the resources, use `Class#getResource`, ie `ImageIO.read(Loader.class.getResource(path))`

Comment: I would also take a closer look at the [JavaDocs for `BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F21%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) as it will present a better example of how you should be using it

Comment: Stupid question, what exactly do you think `g.fillRect(0, 0, Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT);` will do, especially when you call it AFTER `g.drawImage(Asserts.background, 0, 0, Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT, null);`

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you think `g.fillRect(0, 0, Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT);` will do, especially when you call it AFTER `g.drawImage(Asserts.background, 0, 0, Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT, null);`?

```
private void draw() {
    //...
    g.drawImage(Asserts.background, 0, 0, Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT, null);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT);
    //...        
}
```

I would also recommend taking a look at the [JavaDocs for `BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F21%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) as it provides a better example of how it should be used.

I would also encourage you to decouple your concerns.  There is not reason to extend from `JFrame` (and setting the size of the content to the same size as the window is going to cause issues).

Instead, extend from `Canvas` and simple create a `JFrame` to display it.

Don't do `src/skins/`, `src` will not exist once your program is compiled and exported. Instead, make use of the fact that these resources will become embedded (assuming your build process includes them in the resulting Jar). Then, instead of using `File` to try and load the resources, use `Class#getResource`, ie `ImageIO.read(Loader.class.getResource(path))`

For example...

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                ContentView contentView = new ContentView();
                contentView.start();
                frame.add(contentView);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Constants {

        public static int WIDTH = 800;
        public static int HEIGHT = 600;
    }

    // Personally, implementing `Runnable` here is a bad idea
    // as it exposes the `run` method to external callers, now
    // as someone who doesn't know your code, do I call `run`
    // or `start`?
    // I would further decouple this by making a class
    // which acted as the "render engine" and which had a
    // inner class which handled the `Runnable` workflow, but
    // that's me.
    public class ContentView extends Canvas implements Runnable {

        private Thread thread;
        private boolean running = false;
        private final int FPS = 60;
        private double TARGETTIME = 1000000000 / FPS;
        private double delta = 0;
        private int AVERAGEFPS = FPS;

        public ContentView() {
            // Just beware, this is likely not going help you maintain
            // focus and you will probably have issues with your 
            // key listener
            setFocusable(true);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long now = 0;
            long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
            int frames = 0;
            long time = 0;

            init();

            while (running) {
                now = System.nanoTime();
                delta += (now - lastTime) / TARGETTIME;
                time += (now - lastTime);
                lastTime = now;

                if (delta >= 1) {
                    update();
                    draw();
                    delta--;
                    frames++;
                }
                if (time >= 1000000000) {
                    AVERAGEFPS = frames;
                    frames = 0;
                    time = 0;
                }
            }

            stop();
        }

        private void start() {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
            running = true;
        }

        private void stop() {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void update() {
            // Do stuff
        }

        private void draw() {
            BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
            if (bs == null) {
                createBufferStrategy(3);
                return;
            }
            do {
                do {
                    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

                    g.fillRect(0, 0, Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT);
                    g.drawImage(Asserts.background, 0, 0, Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT, null);

                    // paint the rest of the state
                    g.drawString("" + AVERAGEFPS, 10, 10);

                    g.dispose();
                } while (bs.contentsRestored());
                bs.show();
            } while (bs.contentsLost());
        }

        private void init() {
            // Personally, I don't see the point of putting
            // this in a seperate thread, as you're referencing
            // elements you need in your paint pass before they
            // might be loaded
            Asserts.init();
        }

    }

    public class Asserts {

        // Note, you're exposing these properties to unrestricted modifications
        // but other parts of your code which could cause no end of werid
        // issues
        public static boolean loaded = false;
        public static float count = 0;
        public static float MAX_COUNT = 460;

        public static BufferedImage background;

        public static void init() {
            // The leading `/` is important, as the `resources`
            // package isn't contained under your `graphics` 
            // package
            background = loadImage("/resources/background.jpg");
            loaded = true;
        }

        public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
            count++;
            return Loader.ImageLoader(path);
        }
    }

    public class Loader {

        public static BufferedImage ImageLoader(String path) {
            try {
                return ImageIO.read(Loader.class.getResource(path));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why I couldn't see it, I had it before when the background was simply black and the only thing I removed was "g.setColor(Color.BLACK);", thanks for the help

Comment: Again, what do you think `g.fillRect(0, 0, Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT);` is doing and what do you think it's doing to what was previously painted before it?  Now, since the `Graphics` context you're getting is shared, you're expected to reset it (ie fill it), which will "erase" the previous content. So look more closely at your paint workflow and think carefully about what each statement is doing

Comment: it draws a rectangle and then painted it in black, I removed it from painting it in black but I didn't remove it from not painting the rectangle that's why the image was not visible